# Reshaping Multi Indexed DF

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe that is structured like so (similar to a pivot table):

| A | B | December 2022 | January 2023 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | B1 | 100 | 200 |
| A1 | B2 | 101 | 201 |

I'd like to and transpose my dataframe in a way so it reads:

| Month | A | B | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| December 2022 | A1 | B1 | 100 |
| December 2022 | A1 | B2 | 101 |
| January 2023 | A1 | B1 | 200 |
| January 2023 | A1 | B2 | 201 |

etc. I've attempted

`df.T`

But it gives me:

| A | A1 | A1 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| B | B1 | B2 |
| December 2022 | 100 | 101 |
| January 2023 | 200 | 201 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [`pd.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.melt.html):

```
>>> df.melt(id_vars=['A', 'B'], var_name='Month', value_name='Value')
    A   B          Month  Value
0  A1  B1  December 2022    100
1  A1  B2  December 2022    101
2  A1  B1   January 2023    200
3  A1  B2   January 2023    201
```

then to reorder columns, you can use this hack:

```
>>> df.melt(id_vars=['A', 'B'], var_name='Month', value_name='Value') \
      .set_index('Month').reset_index()

           Month   A   B  Value
0  December 2022  A1  B1    100
1  December 2022  A1  B2    101
2   January 2023  A1  B1    200
3   January 2023  A1  B2    201
```

**Update**: according to @sammywemmy's comment:

```
var_cols = ['A', 'B']
out = df.melt(id_vars=var_cols, var_name='Month', value_name='Value') \
        [['Month'] + var_cols + ['Value']]
print(out)

# Output
           Month   A   B  Value
0  December 2022  A1  B1    100
1  December 2022  A1  B2    101
2   January 2023  A1  B1    200
3   January 2023  A1  B2    201
```

Comment: index setting might be expensive, a possibly better option might be to just reorder the columns with `loc` or even reindex on the columns

Comment: @sammywemmy. You are totally right and mostly because the list of columns is needed to fill `id_vars` parameter. I updated my answer.